# Is there a memory efficient way to change the behavior of an inherent implementation?

Tags: rust

Is there a memory efficient way to change the behavior on an inherent implementation?  At the moment, I can accomplish the change of behavior by storing a number of function pointers, which are then called by the inherent implementation.  My difficulty is that there could potentially be a large number of such functions and a large number of objects that depend on these functions, so I'd like to reduce the amount of memory used.  As an example, consider the code:

```rust
// Holds the data for some process
struct MyData {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    fns: MyFns,
}
impl MyData {
    // Create a new object
    fn new(x: f64, y: f64) -> MyData {
        MyData {
            x,
            y,
            fns: CONFIG1,
        }
    }

    // One of our functions
    fn foo(&self) -> f64 {
        (self.fns.f)(self.x, self.y)
    }

    // Other function
    fn bar(&self) -> f64 {
        (self.fns.g)(self.x, self.y)
    }
}

// Holds the functions
struct MyFns {
    f: fn(x: f64, y: f64) -> f64,
    g: fn(x: f64, y: f64) -> f64,
}

// Some functions to use
fn add(x: f64, y: f64) -> f64 {
    x + y
}
fn sub(x: f64, y: f64) -> f64 {
    x - y
}
fn mul(x: f64, y: f64) -> f64 {
    x * y
}
fn div(x: f64, y: f64) -> f64 {
    x / y
}

// Create some configurations
const CONFIG1: MyFns = MyFns {
    f: add,
    g: mul,
};
const CONFIG2: MyFns = MyFns {
    f: sub,
    g: div,
};

fn main() {
    // Create our structure
    let mut data = MyData::new(1., 2.);

    // Check our functions
    println!(
        "1: x={}, y={}, foo={}, bar={}",
        data.x,
        data.y,
        data.foo(),
        data.bar()
    );

    // Change the functions
    data.fns = CONFIG2;

    // Print the functions again
    println!(
        "2: x={}, y={}, foo={}, bar={}",
        data.x,
        data.y,
        data.foo(),
        data.bar()
    );

    // Change a single function
    data.fns.f = add;

    // Print the functions again
    println!(
        "3: x={}, y={}, foo={}, bar={}",
        data.x,
        data.y,
        data.foo(),
        data.bar()
    );
}
```

This code allows the behavior of `foo` and `bar` to be changed by editing `f` and `g`.  However, it also not flexible.  I'd rather use a boxed trait object `Box<dyn Fn(f64,f64)->f64`, but then I can't create some default configurations like `CONFIG1` and `CONFIG2` because `Box` can not be used to create a constant object.  In addition, if we have a large number of functions and objects, I'd like to share the memory for their implementation.  For function pointers, this isn't a big deal, but for closures it is.  Here, we can't create a constant `Rc` for the configuration to share the memory.  Finally, we could have a static reference to a configuration, which would save memory, but then we could not change the individual functions.  I'd rather we have a situation where most of the time we share memory for the functions, but have the ability hold its own memory and change the functions if desired.

I'm open to a better design if one is available.  Ultimately, I'd like to change the behavior of `foo` and `bar` at runtime based on a function held, in some form or another, inside of `MyData`.  Further, I'd like a way to do so where the memory is shared when possible and we have the ability to change an individual function and not just the entire configuration.

Answer (score 2):

A plain `dyn` reference will work here - it allows references to objects that have a certain trait but with type known only at runtime.

(This is exactly what you want for function pointers. Think of it as each function having its own special type, but falling under a trait like `Fn(f64,f64)->f64`.)

So your struct could be defined as:

```
struct MyData<'a> {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    f: &'a dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64,
    g: &'a dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64,
}
```

(Notice, you need the lifetime specifier `'a` to ensure the the lifetime of that references is not shorter than the struct itself.)

Then your impl could be like:

```
impl<'a> MyData<'a> {
    // Create a new object
    fn new(x: f64, y: f64) -> Self {
        MyData {
            x,
            y,
            f: &add, // f and g as in CONFIG1
            g: &mul,
        }
    }

    fn foo(&self) -> f64 {
        (self.f)(self.x, self.y)
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Depending on how you want the default configurations to work, you could either make them as more inherent functions such as `fn to_config2(&mut self);` or you could make a separate struct just with the function pointers and then have a function to copy those function pointers into the `MyData` struct.